# Problems with Flash CS6 Generate Sprite Sheet

Tags: flash, crop, flash-cs6, sprite

I encounter some problems whenever I use the generate sprite sheet function in Flash CS6.

There are always some clips got rotated near the edge of the image like [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/y6eh6fpptnlkdho/-Ps6gNXIwz)

The alphabet "A" is just an rectangular I draw to replace the original image because

it's used in my company that has copyrighted. So it's not the font problem.

Blow is the setting I use:

Algorithm : MaxRects
Data Format : Starling
Trim : Checked
Stack frames : Checked
Shape Padding : 2 or more

I post this same question to the Adobe Forum but no one seems to give solutions.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the sprite sheet, select the Dimension as Auto Size. That should solve your problem. Or just increase the width of the image manually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But actually our team need to set static image size such as 2048*2048. So if there are some other ways instead of adjusting the image size?

Comment: Well, there is no other way I guess, there are not enough space on the 2048*2048 image to draw every image correctly on it.